# Adding CSS code for increasing space between label and radio button

Tags: css, qualtrics

I need to increase the space between the labels (which overlap with my resized radio buttons) and the radio buttons. The code snippets I have found only address the labels being to the left or right of the button. My labels are above the radio button, and now the two line labels (like "neither dislike or like", which spans two lines) are getting overlapped by the radio button. Thank you!

[a screenshot of my radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TchA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add this javascript to your Qualtrics question:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var qid = this.questionId;
    var radioCells = $(qid).select('td.ControlContainer');
    var limit = radioCells.length;
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++) {
        radioCells[i].style.paddingTop = "25px";
    }
});
```

Adjust the "25px" as necessary.  You should consider upgrading to the new Qualtrics themes where the radio buttons go away and the labels become clickable buttons.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santon/yauwpz98/)

As I am not sure if you are using bootstrap or any other layout framework, here is a solution with a simple table layout.

```
td {
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
}

<!--EMMET string  table>(tr>(td>label[for=radio$]{myradio$})*5)+(tr>(td>input#radio$[type='radio'][name=myradio])*5)-->
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label for="radio1">myradio1</label></td>
    <td><label for="radio2">myradio2</label></td>
    <td><label for="radio3">myradio3</label></td>
    <td><label for="radio4">myradio4</label></td>
    <td><label for="radio5">myradio5</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="myradio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="myradio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="myradio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="radio4" name="myradio"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="radio5" name="myradio"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't apply to Qualtrics (it really wasn't obvious from the question, you had to look at the tag).